# php only retrieve number, even as string

Tags: php, android, mysql

So I have this code for retrieving data from mysql with php from android.
It reads the "serial number" that I input and then it reads and retrieves the data as array with that particular SN.

Everything works until I have a serial number which is a mix of numerical and alphabetical characters (AJH871).
It wont retrieve that particular data. Apparently, anything other than number (289173 etc) doesn't work, although there's no error.

Any idea how to solve this?

Here's part of the code:
(here's where the code is retrieved and shown as gettext)

```
class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

/**
 * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
 * */
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
}

/**
 * Getting product details in background thread
 * */
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    // updating UI from Background Thread
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SN",SN));

                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                // Note that product details url will use GET request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_product_details, "GET", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully received product details
                    JSONArray productObj = json
                            .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                    // get first product object from JSON Array
                    JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                    // product with this pid found
                    // Edit Text
                    txtID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputID);
                    txtSerial = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSerial);
                    txtJenis = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputJenis);
                    txtMerk = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputMerk);
                    //txtSpec = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSpec);
                    txtUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputUser);
                    txtDept = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDept);
                    txtCond = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputCond);

                    // display product data in EditText
                    txtID.setText(product.getString(TAG_PID));
                    txtSerial.setText(product.getString(TAG_SERIAL));
                    txtJenis.setText(product.getString(TAG_JENIS));
                    txtMerk.setText(product.getString(TAG_MERK));
                    //txtSpec.setText(product.getString(TAG_SPEC));
                    txtUser.setText(product.getString(TAG_USER));
                    txtDept.setText(product.getString(TAG_DEPT));
                    txtCond.setText(product.getString(TAG_COND));
                    check = 1;

                }else{
                    // product with pid not found                           
                    check = 2;
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(check == 1){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data ditemukan",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(check==2){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID tidak ditemukan",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }
    });


    return null;
}
```

//

here's the jsonparser

```
     public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "utf-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
```

//

and here's the php

```
    if (isset($_GET["SN"])) {
    $SN = $_GET['SN'];

    // get a product from products table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products WHERE SN = $SN");

    if (!empty($result)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $product = array();
            $product["SN"] = $result["SN"];
            $product["label"] = $result["label"];
            $product["jenis"] = $result["jenis"];
            $product["merk"] = $result["merk"];
            $product["user"] = $result["user"];
            $product["dept"] = $result["dept"];
            $product["cond"] = $result["cond"];
            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $response["products"] = array();

            array_push($response["products"], $product);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // no product found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No product found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

//

Sorry if it's a little messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

proper quotes on the SQL query

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products WHERE SN = '$SN'");
```

From this:

```
 SELECT *FROM products WHERE SN = ABC123;
```

To this:

```
 SELECT *FROM products WHERE SN = 'ABC123';
```

Comment: upvote me if this is correct! stackoverflow is banning me for not making uber long posts! haha. kidding.

Comment: thanks! lol, also, my OC-ness wants you to add space after "*", "SELECT * FROM", I dunno, it just looks better :P

Comment: yep, already did it on my code the moment i saw it here, here i thought it wouldnt work if miss a space in php or mysql

Answer (score 0):

I guess you `SN COLUMN` is not an `int` kinda `datatype`.

If it's `varchar` or others `string friendly` `datatypes`  you have to use single quotes after the `=` **(equal sign).**

Something like: `='searchTermHere'` will do, for your case `='$SN'` should do the trick

Comment: yep, didnt know i have to put quotes also for string in php. I guess i learn something new everyday, huh